# Bootplus keeping comments open

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How would you go about keeping the comments in a card open by default..? As of now here's my code:

```
<div class="card">
   <h3 class="card-heading simple">Simple News Card</h3>
   <div class="card-body">
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="card-comments">
      <div class="comments-collapse-toggle">
         <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#c1-comments" href="#c1-comments">34 comments <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div id="c1-comments" class="comments collapse">
         <div class="media">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
               <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/28x28" alt="avatar"/>
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
               <h4 class="media-heading">Comment title</h4>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam...</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

(copied from [Bootplus](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/plus.html))

But the comments are hidden by default and when you click on the **34 comments** link, the comments toggle between open and close..

How would i keep it open by default?

**[DEMO (The first example)](http://aozora.github.io/bootplus/plus.html)**

Comment: may be you want to remove collapse class

Comment: removing collapse deletes the toggle functionality

Comment: Add class `in` to `.comments` and set `style="height: auto"`.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi by `.comments` I mean elements with class `comments`. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: post it as an answer so that i can thank you, better..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can modify the HTML you can do this:

```
<div id="c1-comments" class="comments in collapse" style="height: auto">
```

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Thanks! Come back and accept later, no problem.